# an alternative to mysqldump?

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, I am having serious problems with MYSQLDump, We have a dedicated server here for our main domain and I am running the following command:

```
mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u root -p ***** --all-databases > ~/var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/db.sql
```

and I get nothing :(

But more importantly, I don't have root access to every server I have access to.  But I **do** have database username and passwords.  Surely there is a PHP only way of dumping the entire contents of a SQL database?

Comment: `~/var/www/vhosts/...` will create a subdirectory in your user directory, is that what you intended?

Comment: You don't need root access to do mysqldumps, do you?

Comment: Don't confuse MySQL's `root` user with system's `root`.

Comment: I think he means Telnet/SSH access (without which running `mysqldump` can be difficult)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I was not aware there was a MySQL root.  How on earth do I go about finding that out?  and I was trying to run mysqldump with shell_exec.

Answer (score 0):

then why don't you use your user/password for the databases to do a per database dump as described i.e. here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/mysqldump.html

mysqldump [options] --databases db_name1 [db_name2 db_name3...]

i just know two options to backup mysql-databases. One is to use mysqldump, the other one is to stop the mysql-server and backup the databasefiles. Doing dumps using PHP or whatever will last longer and cause much more trouble then just using mysqldump!

Comment: i cant even get mysqldump to work though, All i get is simply null which is very frustrating, there are no proper error messages or anything.

Comment: just try mysqldump database1 -uusername -ppasswort backup.sql this should give you a backup.sql file for database1!

Comment: and don't use root if you don't have the password for the mysql-root user. On some systems mysql-root does not need a password when accessing from localhost, but might require one when doing the same from a different host.

Comment: i get absolutely NO response! No matter what I try, it's so frustrating

Comment: I've tried my server root password and also the password I use in PHP to access the database but I get nothing :(

Comment: I dont get this!!! Having not set up this server, it's simply a dedicated server that rackspace are hosting, we have not been told the mySQL root password! :(

Comment: your php.ini should give you enough hints! Questions to answer are: do you use IP connections to your database? Which port? Or do you have to use sockets ( mysqldump works with sockets too)? Next thing is, that mysql differs user/host combinations. Perhaps you will have to take your user and the servers name instead of localhost or.... you will have to search a while, but PHP should give you enough hints on that!

Answer (score 0):

> I was not aware there was a MySQL root.

Well, then that's the most likely cause of your problems, since you have this:

```
mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u root -p *****
                             ^^^^^^^
```

The `-u` parameter expects a MySQL user and you are probably feeding it with systems' `root` user, which is something entirely different.

If you have a separate user for each database, I'm afraid you'll have to issue separate dumps.

Additionally, try to fetch error messages. You can [redirect](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) `stderr` to `stdout` by appending the  `2>&1` operator to your command and you can grab output from [shell_exec()](http://php.net/shell_exec)'s return.

Answer (score 0):

In the mysqldump command there is no space after -p and the password so your line should look like:

```
mysqldump --opt -h localhost -u root -p***** --all-databases > /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/db.sql
```